# PSU failure (BSOD when trying to start computer)

Tags: bsod

A few days ago, one of my computers completely went down with BSOD. Since then, I've not been able to get the computer to fire back up. Basically, I turn it on, it makes loud beeping, then shuts back down. I tried switching out the RAM to see if it was a memory issue, but no use. I also did some research to see if anyone had a similar issue. Unfortunately, I was unable to get any answers related to mine.

Ultimately what this all comes down to, I'm beginning to wonder if this is possible PSU failure. I don't want to go on a replacement spree until I'm able to find what the issue may be and without gathering information by you guys.

Comment: WIthout knowing the beep pattern or BSOD this seems hard to answer. Useful information here would be the brand and model of the computer, and the beep pattern (which is trivial to look up). If the system still booted, whocrashed or blue screen view might have useful information.

Comment: Instead of making random guesses, pay attention to the loud beeping. Your BIOS is trying to tell you what is wrong. Jot down the beep pattern and look up beep codes for your BIOS/motherboard brand.

Comment: @Substantial Thank you. I did not realize that the beeping meant anything. I have replaced the RAM and everything now works fine.